# JavaScript Calculation?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function Submit() {
var city=0;
    if (document.getElementById("louis").checked){
        city=40;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("milwaukee").checked){
    city=20;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("detroit").cheked){
    city=35;
    }

var hotel=0;
    if (document.getElementById("economy").checked){
        hotel=50;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("standard").checked){
    hotel=70;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("upscale").cheked){
    hotel=120;
    }

var numtravelers = parseInt(document.getElementById("travelers").value);

var daystravel = parseInt(document.getElementById("day").value);
var mealchoice=0;
    if (document.getElementById("none").checked){
        mealchoice=0;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("snack").checked){
    mealchoice=5;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("fullmeal").cheked){
    mealchoice=10;
    }


var extra=0;
    if (document.getElementById("Wifi").checked){
        extra=10;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("recline").checked){
    extra=20;
    }


var cost=0;



cost=(city*numtravelers)+(hotel*daystravel)+(numtravelers*mealchoice)+(numtravelers*extra);
document.getElementById("OutputResult").innerHTML="your total cost is $" + cost.toString();






}
```

```css
body
{background-color: #000080;
color: #C0C0C0;}
 a {
   color: #00ffff;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #00ff00;
 }

 form {color: #00ffff;


 }

 h1 {font-style: italic;
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFD700;
   font-family: Helvetica;
   border-style: solid;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: gold;
 }

 footer {
font-style: italic;
font-family: cursive;
text-align: center;
color: #FFFFFF;


 }

#contact {
  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Make a Reservation</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="reservation_javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final_project_css.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="nav">
        <nav>
            <a href="reservation.htm">Make a Reservation</a>
            <a href="contact.htm">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="mailing.htm">Join Our Mailing List</a>
            <a href="busline_home.htm">Home</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
<div> <h1> Mad Men Bus Company </h1> </div>

      <form name="reservation">
          <p>First Name: <input type="text"></p>
          <p>Last Name: <input type="text"></p>

      <p>Arrival City:</p>
            St. Louis($40)<input type="radio" name="Arrival" id="louis" value="40"/><br>
            Milwaukee($20)<input type="radio" name="Arrival" id="milwaukee" value="20"/><br>
            Detroit($35)<input type="radio" name="Arrival" id="detroit" value="35"/><br>


      <p>Hotel Choice:</p>
            Economy($50/day)<input type="radio" name="Hotel" id="economy" value="50"/><br>
            Standard($70/day)<input type="radio" name="Hotel" id="standard" value="70"/><br>
            Upscale($120/day)<input type="radio" name="Hotel"id="upscale" value="120"/><br>

        <p>Number of Travelers</p>
<select id="travelers">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<p>Number of Days</p>
    <select id="day">
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>


        <p>Extras</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="Wifi" value="10">Wifi<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="recline" value="20">Fully-reclining seat<br>
<div id="Meal">
        <p>Meal Choice:</p>

            None<input type="radio" name="Meal" id="none"/></br>
            Snack($5)<input type="radio" name="Meal" id="snack" value="5"/></br>
            Full Meal($10)<input type="radio" name="Meal" id="fullmeal" value="10"/></br>
</div>


        <p>Special Requests:</p>
        <input type="text" name="SpecialRequests"/>
<div>


<br><input type="button" value="Book My Trip" onclick="Submit()">

</div>

<h1 id="Total">Total</h1>

<div id="OutputResult">

</div>

</form>

<footer>
100 Manly Avenue New York, New York 10016, 555-555-5555, info@madmenbusline.com
</footer>



  </body>
</html>
```

When the user chooses upscale hotel choice and or detroit each of those options returns a value of 0 when I click to calculate total cost. I have the right value assigned to them I'm confused why it is not adding the price that I associated with each of those two variables. I do not think my else if statements are wrong... Can someone provide me a hint as to why it may not be working?

Comment: `cheked` <- well there's your first problem...

Comment: ^ You have multiple places where you write `cheked` instead of `checked`. In coding, spelling is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the user chooses upscale hotel choice and or detroit

You have spelled `checked` incorrectly in both of those places. In this situation, `cheked` will return `undefined` which is falsy. Therefore you will get a `0` instead of your expected number

All you need to is fix

```
else if (document.getElementById("detroit").cheked){
```

and

```
else if (document.getElementById("upscale").cheked){
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I made such a rookie mistake I apologize.